# stackview in custom table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistackview

In a custom table cell, I'm trying to hide/show view on a button click. I'm able to achieve this but couldn't able to remove the blank space. How to remove those blank spaces. I used auto constraints for stack view but it seems to be no use. can you anyone suggest a simple way to remove the blank spaces when the view is in a hidden state.

**Note:** *custom cell should adjust its height automatically depending on the content when it's attached to table view*

**Edit one**

[image: As you can see the start date and end date are placed at the bottom without any dynamic height change]

As you can see the start date and end date are placed at the bottom without any dynamic height change

[image: Preview of the custom cell. In this Cell stack view at the bottom is set to hidden initially.]

Preview of the custom cell. In this Cell stack view at the bottom is set to hidden initially.

Comment: are you reloading the cell after you make the changes?

Comment: how do you define the cell height? is it .dimensional? Do you reload table cell on update? Blank space? You should update your question, from my point it is pretty vague.

Comment: Show some code of what you tried.

Comment: for height im using "UITableViewAutomaticDimension"

Comment: You can create few constraints and switch between on button click

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options...

---

1) Use another stack view:

- Embed the top "always visible" elements in a `UIView`
- Embed that view and the "sometimes hidden" stack view in a vertical "outer" stack view
- Constrain this new "outer" stack view to all 4 sides of the cell's content view

Now, when you hide the "sometimes hidden" stack view, it will not take up any space.

---

2) Use multiple bottom constraints:

- Keep the bottom constraint from the bottom of the "sometimes hidden" stack view to the bottom of the cell's content view. Make it an `IBOutlet` - we'll call it `whenHiddenConstraint`
- Add a constraint from the bottom of the bottom-most "always visible" element to the bottom of the cell's content view. Make it an `IBOutlet` - we'll call it `whenVisibleConstraint`
- Set the Priority on the `whenVisibleConstraint` to `750`
- Set the Priority on the `whenHiddenConstraint` to `250`

Now, in your code, when hiding the "sometimes hidden" stack view:

```
theStackView.isHidden = true
whenVisibleConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
whenHiddenConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
```

when you want to show the "sometimes hidden" stack view:

```
theStackView.isHidden = false
whenHiddenConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
whenVisibleConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
```